# Highstock graph showing data outside selected range

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I have an implementation of a Highstock graph where the chart is narrowed in width in order to fit two of them side by side. A consequence of this seems to be some data bleeding over from the left graph to the right. Even when there is only one graph narrowed in width by itself it seems to still happen.

The data that bleeds over cannot be seen unless you hover over it. The halo and tooltip appear for the data point despite being outside of the selected range in the navigator.

[Hovering over a point outside of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auiMS.png)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7dk6g6rh/

```js
var stockChart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    xAxis: {    
        width: '500',
        type: 'datetime'
    },
  series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 8],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2004, 3, 1),
        pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
    }]
});

stockChart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1080777600000, 1080806400000);
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of using min-width, use only width. this will shorten not only the width of chart but also the width of navigator. please check http://jsfiddle.net/7dk6g6rh/1/

Comment: I can still see the extra data point in your solution. The length of the navigator is not the problem, it's the extra data point that appears when hovering just to the right of the graph (see screenshot posted in original question).

Comment: if u remove set extreme  line , u will get the desired result. please check http://jsfiddle.net/7dk6g6rh/2/

Comment: Thank you, but the desired result would be to set the extremes (or have a user set them using the navigator) and not be able to hover over that data point :)

Comment: this link might help you to set extremes in highstock .   http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Axis.setExtremes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by [extending Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) to behave how I wanted it to. I wrapped the Tooltip, Point, and Axis functions (refresh, setState, and drawCrosshair respectively) to make some checks before proceeding to normal operation.

Here is the JSFiddle with the correct behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/7dk6g6rh/7/

```js
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function(proceed, points) {
        for(var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
            if(!points[i].isInside) {
                this.hide();
                return;
            }
        }
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'setState', function(proceed, state) {
        if(this.isInside || state !== 'hover') {
            proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
    });
    H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'drawCrosshair', function(proceed) {
        var hoverPoint = this.chart.hoverPoint; 
        if(hoverPoint && hoverPoint.isInside) {
            proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else {
            this.hideCrosshair();
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));

var stockChart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    xAxis: {    
        width: '500',
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 8],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2004, 3, 1),
        pointInterval: 3600 * 1000
    }]
});

stockChart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1080777600000, 1080806400000);
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```